# How can I kill Excel.exe through .NET code?

Tags: c#, excel

Actually I'm writing a small application (WinForms + C#), where I'm reading the Excel file. After exiting from the application and went to the task manager I found that Excel.exe is still running. And as I run my application several times I found multiple instances of Excel.exe running in the task manager.

So can somebody tell me as what needs to be done to kill "Excel.exe" each time I exit from the application...

The code is somewhat like this:

```
ApplicationClass appClass = new ApplicationClass();
Workbook workBook = appClass.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
Worksheet workSheet = (Worksheet) workBook.ActiveSheet;
```

All under this namespace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; that is **COM**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How are you reading the Excel file? If you're using COM, you need to call `Application.Quit` when you're finished.

**Edit:** from the code in your comment -

```
//Initializing the application class
ApplicationClass appClass = new ApplicationClass();
try
{
    Workbook workBook = appClass.Workbooks.Open(path,0,true,5,"","",true,XlPlatform.xlWindows,"\t",false,false,0,true,1,0);
    Worksheet workSheet = (Worksheet)workBook.ActiveSheet;
    // do stuff with the workbook
}
finally
{
    appClass.Quit();
}
```

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass, yes COM.
Actually i am getting the information from the Excel and showing it the user in Datagrid view. Now its upto the user to close that application using "Close" button.
I hope you got a hint now as what i am doing, any suggestions now ?

Comment: As an aside, you should not use ApplicationClass. Quote the documentation: "This class supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.", use Application instead.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of killing the processes... why don't you dispose your Excel-handles correctly instead? Sounds like you open instances of Excel without ever closing them properly.
It's generally a good idea to also release acquired resources after using them.

Comment: I tried using Marshal.ReleaseComObject(handler). But its not working :(

Comment: As far as I can tell by your comments to ChrisF's answer, you're using the com interface via interop. In this case call the Quit-Method of the instance (as Tim Robinson pointed out)

Answer (score 3):

```
Process[] pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");

            pro[0].Kill();
            pro[0].WaitForExit();
```

its easy like this. you can get process by name, id etc. just go to your process, Kill(), and WaitForExit();

Comment: Simple and easy way to kill the excel process. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this example - http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1543.htm

It uses the Process.Kill() method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx

Comment: This will not work as its quite possible that other application might be working using Excel.exe. So this will kill all the instances of the "Excel" process.

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that you are launching Excel via [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx). The code wasn't posted until later.

In that case keep hold of the process handle returned by that call and then use that to call [`Process.CloseMainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) followed by [`Process.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx):

```
Process ExcelProcess;  // Declaration
```

Store the process handle:

```
ExcelProcess = Process.Start(...);
```

Then when you exit your application:

```
// Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
ExcelProcess.CloseMainWindow();
// Free resources associated with process.
ExcelProcess.Close();
```

Comment: Btw, `Process.Close` doesn't exit a process; it just cleans up your app's copy of the process handle. Failing to call `Process.Close` doesn't prevent the process from exiting.

Comment: @Tim - Cheers, I thought `Kill` was a bit over the top & changed my answer, but forgot about the call the `CloseMainWindow`

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass. The code is somewhat like this: 
 //Initializing the application class
            ApplicationClass appClass = new ApplicationClass();
            Workbook workBook = appClass.Workbooks.Open(path,0,true,5,"","",true,XlPlatform.xlWindows,"\t",false,false,0,true,1,0);
            Worksheet workSheet = (Worksheet)workBook.ActiveSheet;

Comment: @Amit - update your question with this code - it'll be much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in some task the excel instance still running after I did a app.Quit() call.

My solution was:

```
application = null;
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Put app instance as null and do a forced call to GC.

Hope this help